# Is it possible to use the Rythm Template Engine with Grails?

Tags: templates, spring-mvc, grails, groovy, template-engine

Is it possible to use the Rythm Template Engine with Grails?  Or for that matter, is it possible to configure a different template engine with Grails?  Spring MVC lets you do this quite easily, by adding a different bean in the context.xml.

Comment: I'm sure it's possible (Since Grails is built on Spring). You could look at the source code for the freemarker plugin to see how it's done too. http://grails.org/plugin/freemarker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same mechanism as Spring, specify a different `ViewResolver` bean